# Remove Improper Input Validation vulnerability from 'xmldom'

Tags: security, soap, xmldom, npm-vulnerabilities, xml-crypto

My project has a new Improper Input Validation vulnerability found by Synk. The problematic library is 'xmldom' version 0.1.19. Looking into the dependency tree, 'xmldom' is required by 'xml-crypto', which is ultimately required by 'soap'. What is the best way to resolve this vulnerability?

Thank you!

I would like to remove the problematic library and replace it with one that is better supported.